# Need help erasing and inserting in C++

Tags: c++, insert, erase

So basically I want to create a format function that accepts a string, and replaces words in that string with whatever the user wants to be replaced. At first I had some issues with non-deferencable iterators until I realized that when you change the the size of a string you can invalid any iterators. It doesn't throw anymore exceptions now now the output is the same as the input. Any advice???

```
string& formatFn(string& s, string& oldWord, string& newWord)
{
    string word = "";
    for (auto iter1 = s.begin(); iter1 != s.end(); ++iter1)
    {       
            string tmpWord = "";                         
        if (!isblank(*iter1))       // Testing for whitespace
        {
            tmpWord += *iter1;
            if (tmpWord == oldWord)
            {
                string::iterator beg = iter1 - word.size();
                string::iterator end = iter1;
                auto sIter = s.erase(beg, end);                 // Get the position returned by erase
                auto i = sIter - s.begin();                     // Get an index 
                s = s.insert(s[i], newWord);
            }
        }
        if (isblank(*iter1))
        {
            tmpWord.clear();
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use `string::find` and `string::replace` for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
string::iterator beg = iter1 - word.size();
```

I'm not sure what `word` actually does. You are trying to delete `oldWord`, right? Then it should be:

```
string::iterator beg = iter1 - oldWord.size();
```

**EDIT :** This is an improved version of your code:

```
string formatFn(const string& s, const string& oldWord, const string& newWord) {
    string result = "";     // holds the string we want to return
    string word = "";       // while iterating over 's', holds the current word

    for (auto iter1 = s.begin(); iter1 != s.end(); ++iter1)  {       
        if (!isblank(*iter1))
            word += *iter1;
        else {    // if it is a whitespace, it must be the end of some word
            // if 'word' is not same as 'oldword', just append it
            // otherwise append 'newWord' instead

            if (word == oldWord)
                result += newWord;
            else
                result += word;
            result += *iter1;
            word.clear();    // reset 'word' to hold the next word in s
        }
    }

    // the end of the string might not end with a whitespace, so the last word
    // might be skipped if you don't make this test

    if (word == oldWord)
        result += newWord;
    else
        result += word;

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already use string why don`t use all methods?

```
for (auto it = text.find(o_text); it != string::npos; it = text.find(o_text)){
    text.replace(it, o_text.size(), n_text);
}
```

Comment: It seems the OP wants to replace *words*, find will find any substring, not just whole words.

Answer (score 0):

You are over-complicating it:

```
std::string replace_all(std::string s, const std::string& sOld, const std::string& sNew)
{
    std::size_t p = s.find(sOld);
    while (p != std::string::npos)
    {
        s.replace(p, sOld.length(), sNew);
        p = s.find(sOld, p + sNew.length());
    }
    return s;
}
```

If you are looking to replace whole words only (which your current attempt will not do):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool test(const std::string& s, const std::string& sOld, std::size_t pos)
{
    return (pos == 0 || !::isalpha(s[pos - 1])) && (!::isalpha(s[pos + sOld.length()]) || pos + sOld.length() >= s.length());
}

std::size_t find_word(const std::string& s, const std::string& sOld, std::size_t pos)
{
    pos = s.find(sOld, pos);
    while (pos != std::string::npos && (!test(s, sOld, pos) && pos < s.length()))
    {
        pos++;
        pos = s.find(sOld, pos);
    }
    return pos;
}

std::string replace_all(std::string s, const std::string& sOld, const std::string& sNew)
{
    std::size_t p = find_word(s, sOld, 0);
    while (p != std::string::npos && p < s.length()) 
    {
        s.replace(p, sOld.length(), sNew);
        p = find_word(s, sOld, p + sNew.length()); 
    }
    return s;
}

int main() 
{
    std::string sOrig = "eat Heat eat beat sweat cheat eat";
    std::string sOld = "eat";
    std::string sNew = "ate";
    std::string sResult = replace_all(sOrig, sOld, sNew);
    std::cout << "Result:  " << sResult << std::endl;
    // Output:  "ate Heat ate beat sweat cheat ate"
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the OP requirements are to replace *words*, not any substring. That's why he has all the whitespace handling.

Comment: Why not accept a reference to a string and mutate that? You can then return the number of words replaced, e.g. `std::size_t replace_all(std::string& s, const std::string& old, const std::string& new);`

Comment: @rwols:  You could do that, but that would change the original.  This way takes a temporary and returns it (equivalent to passing by const-reference and making a copy), leaving the original in tact.  If having the original modified is acceptable, then returning `void` and passing by reference works as well.  The point is more the algorithm.

Comment: @john:  If you only pass words in as your `sOld`, then all that gets replaced are matching words (no need to worry about whitespace).

Comment: Additionally, if he wants to pass in multiple words in the `sOld` parameter and replace them all with what is in `sNew`, it is a fairly simple matter to change the parameter type for `sOld` to a `const std::vector<std::string>&` modify the algorithm to loop over all of the `sOld`'s to do the replacements.

Comment: @ZacHowland Huh? If I want, say, to replace "eat" with "ate", then with your code "heat" will also get changed to "hate". The OP isn't over-complicating, you are over-simplifying.

Comment: @john And to get around that (in my solution), you could pass " eat" with " ate".  His current attempt avoids whitespace, which would prevent you from doing that.

Comment: This approach can be used, if you at the beginning of the function add a space in front of and at the end of both sOld and sNew. They should in that case be passed by value rather than const reference.

Comment: @Zyx2000:  The contents of sOld and sNew have no bearing on how they should be passed.  Since neither of them are being modified, passing them as const-reference is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @ZacHowland His code is bugged so it doesn't do anything at all. But it's clearly an attempt to replace whole words only. Something which your code doesn't and which seems only to have occurred to you when I mentioned it.

Comment: @ZacHowland Using " eat" and " ate" doesn't work to replace the first word.

Comment: @john:  Primarily because the OP DIDN'T mention it.  It was a requirement you added after the fact, and frankly, isn't a problem that is too hard to solve with what I've posted already.  In fact ... I'll do just that (just to make you happy) :-P

Comment: Quoted from the question, "replaces words in that string", plus the clear intent in the code, what you called over-complicating is nothing of the sort. Just try looking at his code and how he tries to handle whitespace.

Comment: @john  His handling of whitespace is completely unnecessary and his attempt to do what you say he is trying to do does not work logically, must less programmatically.  My original answer fixed his programmatic problems ... the latter fixes your perceived logical problems.  Both with much more simple code than he was trying to utilize.